# Python - How extract specific numbers from strings?

Tags: python

I have a series of strings in the follow pattern:
`string = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'`. 
I need to extract the last digits in order to make an ID. I tried to use the `isdigit` method, but the problem is that it also returns the digit before the 
Name.

Caveats:

1. Sometimes the name doesn't come with the digit.
2. `len` from last digits ranges from 5 to 9.

Could anyone suggest to me an alternative?
I think that I need to test if the the previous position or next position are digits in order to extract the id, but I cant figure out how to implement this test.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regex:

```
import re


pattern = re.compile('\d{5,9}$')

for match in pattern.findall('ABCD 1NAME 123456'):
    print(match)
```

**Output**

```
123456
```

The above regex means:

- `\d{5,9}` match a group of 5 - 9 digits
- `$` means that the group of digits must be at the end, if the group can be anywhere in the string just remove this symbol.

Answer (score 2):

I agree and believe @DanielMesejo response is the best solution to my knowledge, but just to offer an alternative idea.

**Solution**

You could create a list and store all the `[-1]` indices from each string in it.

```
string = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'
string = string.split()
num_ids = []
num_ids.append(string[-1])
```

Could use this with a loop to extract for all.

**With loop:**

```
strings = ['ABCD 1NAME 123456','BHDU 1NAME 45678','OIUS 1NAME 109028']
num_ids = []
for string in strings:
    string = string.split()
    num_ids.append(string[-1])
print(num_ids)
```

**Optional with comprehension**

as mention by @Alexander

```
strings = ['ABCD 1NAME 123456','BHDU 1NAME 45678','OIUS 1NAME 109028']
num_ids = [string.split()[-1] for string in strings]
print(num_ids)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 pattern.py 
> ['123456', '45678', '109028']
> ```

Comment: `num_ids.append(string[-1])` to be more safe.  Using a list comprehension: `ids = [string.split()[-1] for string in my_strings]`

Comment: good point, was just assuming since OP said this format was consistent, but I agree its safer to go with `[-1]` , updating

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split the string by spaces and then index it with `-1` to extract the id portion.

```
string = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'
val=string.split()
print(val[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `rsplit()`?

```
s = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'
print(s.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])
# 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using a for loop to iterate the string in question

```
string = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'

for i in string:
    if i.isdigit():
        print(i)
```

You probably should use split():

```
string = 'ABCD 1NAME 123456'

for i in string.split():
    if i.isdigit():
        print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably do:

```
a = string.split()
if a[-1].isdigit():
    print(a[-1])
```

This splits the string and outputs rightmost one if it is indeed a series of digits.